# Euler's Phi function works for non dividing primes as well, why?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose we take a number $n$. We choose primes $p_1, p_2, p_3, \cdots, p_k$ such that $\forall$ $1\leq i\leq k$, $GCD(p_i,n)$ is not necessarily equal to $p_i$; it can be $1$ as well. In other words, they must not necessarily divide $n$ or be coprime to it.

In this case, if we want to find the count of numbers from $1$ to $n$ which are coprime to each and every $p_i$, we can apply the Euler's Phi function in something as this way : ${n \prod{(1-\frac{1}{p_i})}}$ and then we get the count. **It's just a good approximation and is quite near to the count. Not exact if the primes don't divide $n$**

Can anyone explain me the reason behind it? Note that the primes may necessarily not divide $n$.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question unless you clarify what "though not exactly that function" means for us to replace that function with.

Comment: @SridharRamesh Edited. What I meant was- it's not exactly Euler's Phi function as it's defined as a way to get all numbers less than or equal to $n$ and are prime to it. So I said like that.. Now edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim you make, as it stands, is false. Consider $k = 1$, $p_1 = 2$, and $n = 3$. The number of integers from $1$ to $3$ which are coprime to $2$ is $2$, which is not $\lfloor 3 \times (1 - 1/2) \rfloor = 1$.

If the claim is just about what's a good approximation: well, fixing $k$ and $p_1, ..., p_k$, note that any $n$ is in some sense near a multiple of all the $p_i$ (the distance being at most a constant; specifically, (half) the product of all the $p_i$), so that, given that the formula works perfectly well when all the $p_i$ DO divide $n$, we thus have that in general the count using this formula can be off by at most that same constant.